# Decrypt game data with public key

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm building a game which stores the maps and worlds data on the device (both tmx, json and Luna scripts).

I want to protect these files so they won't be editable by others.

I thought that I'd be a good idea to create a self-signed certificate, store the public key on the device and then sign the files before distributing the game using the private key and in the game, decrypt the game using the on-device public key.

This approach got 2 problems (as I learned when searching the net):
1. The public/private key does not intended to decrypt files. I can solve this problem by hashing a random key and then use it for AES encryption.
2. The **public key** should be used to encrypt and not the **private key**.

So my questions is:
A. Is my approach to handle files correct ? (Using AES with hashes key)
B. Am I missing something? Can the encryption be done using the private key and then decrypt with the public key? Alternatively, what can I do to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You want signing, not encryption.

Comment: you've got it wrong. pub/priv keys are exactly what you want. you encrypt your maps with the private key,, and then ONLY the public key (which your users have) can decrypt/use the maps. they wouldn't be able to modify them, because they'd have no way to re-encrypt them. they've only got your public key, and it can't decrypt what it itself has encrypted.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for your comment! I'm bit confused - Can I **encrypt** the maps using the private key? I've managed to sign them using the private key, but couldn't **encrypt** them using the private key. Is it possible? Alternatively, Should I only sign the files w/o encrypting them?

Comment: you can encrypt with either key. the main thing that is you can't DECRYPT the file with the same key you used for the encrypting. that's why they're called public and private. there's really no difference between the two, except one you HAVE to keep private.

Answer (score 3):

You should not *encrypt* the data. Just *sign* it using the digital signature, like DSA.

There's absolutely no sense in encrypting, if anyone is allowed to decrypt.

P.S. As you probably do not possess the signature approved by some well-known authorization center, may be, it will be better just to provide hashes for all files on your site.

Comment: It's OK, but only if you are absolutely sure, that the users have the right copy of your public key. Or else, the evildoer can change files, generate some new key, sign files with this "new" key, and give the "new" public key to users instread of yours.